# Force Standards/Quirks Mode in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, standards-compliance, quirks-mode

Is there a way to force Standards/Quirks mode from the browser (similar to what IE does) in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Use the quirksmode stylesheets of [Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/quirks.css) or [Gecko](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/quirk.css) and toggle it on or off in one of several ways:

- [User Stylesheet](http://brugbart.com/Articles/custom-style-sheets)
- [Style Switcher](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/bodyswitchers/)
- [CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/)
- [DOM Level 2 Style API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found that not including a DOCTYPE like `<!DOCTYPE html>` leads to quirks mode, where for example `width: 100%` suffices instead of `width: -moz-available; width: -webkit-fill-available; width: available;`